# Spring websocket - client CORS policy error

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am using websockets to communicate between server and client. I followed this documentation to implement websocket dependecy. Now when I try to connect via example client page it produces the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '....' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I have tried adding `.setAllowedOrigins("*")` to `WebSocketConfig` but it didn't fix this. What is the solution?

Comment: Does your client use SockJs?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your client application and configuration a bit more?

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad yes, it's using sockJs

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says you are sending a request with credentials set to include, I guess you are sending some kind of token/access data with your request.

When doing so your server must respond with the correct origin. If you are in development try setting your localhost. For example .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080") or what ever you are using. In production you need to replace that with your deployment url.

Comment: I am in development and deploying client page (html page using sockjs and stomp js) independently.

Comment: Ok, good so have you got it to work with setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:YOUR_PORT_HERE") on your server?

Comment: no, I got the same message. Isn't `*` supposed to cover all domains?

Comment: It is not allowed when sending credentials, you must specify protocol + adress + port as correct origin on your server.

Comment: I guessed as much, though full domain address isn't working either

Comment: Did you add it with protocol? Try adding correct content-type header to your request if you have not all ready. Check network tab in chrome for exact headers sent.

Answer (score 0):

You might find success with `.setAllowedOriginsPattern("*")`.

See the [following documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#setAllowedOriginPatterns-java.util.List-) for more stricter patterns.